# can not display file content in text view

Tags: java, android, textview, android-alertdialog

i am trying to select a file from the alert dialog and when i press OK i should display the content of the selected file in a text View by using the method display Content() that take the selected file read it and display the content line by line, but it does not display anything and i think the problem is with the call because i already use the method in another app and it work.

this is the code i have and how i call displayContent()

```
            AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dialogBuilder.setTitle("Single Choice List")
                    .setSingleChoiceItems(files, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            selectionID = which;
                        }
                    })
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            //display the content of the selected file
                            displayContent();
                            Toast.makeText(View_Records.this, "You selected " + files[selectionID], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    })
```

this is the code for displayContent():

```
private void displayContent(){

    try {
        myFilesDirectory = new File(getFilesDir(), "MyFiles");
        String fileName = files[selectionID] + ".txt";
        File file = new File(myFilesDirectory, fileName);
        String text;
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(text).append("\n");
        }
        txtViewRecords.setText(sb.toString());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Well, would be nice if you could show us `displayContent()`

Comment: sure, i will add it now

Comment: I'm not sure if it might be this, but I have it made like `br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));` Have you checked if code inside `try{}` is being executed? Or maybe it throws `Exception`?

Comment: And what about `try{ } catch()`? Try to debug it and check if something goes wrong during `try` block.

Comment: i try it but the same problem :( and it didn't throw any Exception, is the method call position right because its the first time i work with this AlertDialog.

Comment: Are you getting right file inside `Toast`? And where is your `txtViewRecords` placed?

Comment: yes, it placed in the same activity i show the alert dialog on if you mean this

Comment: Does it really need to be `AlertDialog`? I'm not sure but it works on another thread to prevent freezing an app, and I don't know if you can manipulate `Views` which are on main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dialogBuilder.setTitle("Single Choice List")
                    .setSingleChoiceItems(files, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            selectionID = which;
                        }
                    })
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            //display the content of the selected file
                            displayContent();
                            Toast.makeText(View_Records.this, "You selected " + files[selectionID], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    })
```

with calling for another `Activity` (`startActivityForResult()`) with `dialog` style where you will pick a `File` and return it's path with `Intent` and then inside `onActivityResult()` you just use it to open `File` and then display it's content inside `TextView`.

Otherwise you can try to use `create()` first and add `onDismissListener()`. Like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
// do you things with builder
AlertDialog ad = builder.create();
ad.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                // here you open file, read content and put it inside TextView`
            }
        });
ad.show()
```

I'm not sure, but this should do the job with `AlertDialog` without creating `Activity` for this.

This is for getting all files from directory:

```
public static ArrayList<File> listFiles(File folder) {
        if (folder.isDirectory()) {
            ArrayList<File> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
            File[] files = folder.listFiles();
            for (File inFile : files) {
                if (!inFile.isDirectory()) {
                    tempList.add(inFile);
                }
            }
            /*Collections.sort(tempList, new Comparator<File>() { //you can sort by name
                @Override
                public int compare(File file1, File file2) {
                    return file1.getName().compareTo(file2.getName());
                }
            });*/
            return tempList;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And you just send `myFilesDirectory` as a parameter.
Also you can skip checking `if(!inFile.isDirectory())` if you are 100% sure that all files are files, not directories and return `Array`.
And then you just get your file using `list.get(selectionID)` or `array[selectionID]` depending what you are going to return from method.

Also method doesn't need to be `static`. I've got it `static` for my project needs.

Comment: i know this way works good thank you, but actually i must use AlertDialog as my instructor request

Comment: sorry sir i just notice that in the method displayContent() it throw an exception file not found that is why there is nothing displayed and i don't know how i can fix this

Comment: And I've noticed that I don't know where you got `files[selectionID]` from

Comment: files is the list that contain the files in the directory and selectionID is what the user choose from the alert dialog list

Comment: And check again if `selectionID` gives you proper value. If not, make it static. It may be your problem, cause you get this value on `Dialog` thread and `Listener` is "listening" on `Activity` thread.

Comment: i check that, it gives me proper value, the mistake was in the name of the file 'String fileName = files[selectionID] + ".txt";
 ' there is no need for .txt since this 'files[selectionID] ' will give me the full name, but after i correct this the app crush i don't know why i think it should be work now everything look OK the path, the way i read !

Comment: That's why I've added code to get path. Check what path are you getting using debugger. Also you can edit post and paste error stack trace.